Integral with min
While solving some problem, I have reached an intermediate step in which I need to calculate the following integral:
$\int_0^1\min (x,1-x) \cdot x dx$
I'm stuck with the calculation, trying to use some kind of geometric trick here. I will be glad to have some of your ideas.

$min(x,1-x)=x \iff x\le 1-x \iff x\le 1/2$

Thanks! It turned out to be very simple!

As @hamam_Abdallah stated in his comment, there holds
$$ \min(x,1-x) = x \iff x \leqslant 1/2. $$
Therefore, you can compute your integral as follows:
$$ \int_0^1 \min(x,1-x) \cdot x \, dx = \int_0^{1/2} x^2 \, dx + \int_{1/2}^1 (1-x) x\, dx. $$
I believe you should be able to compute the latter two integrals, but if you need more details about this last calculation please let me know.
